# Proper way to hook for POJO model update in jface databinding

Tags: data-binding, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am new to the JFace databindings. I have an EditorPage in Eclipse(Eclipse Luna 4.4) with some custom widgets/controls. I created the databindings between the controls and the POJOs and the POJOs are updated correctly. To maintain the dirty state of the editor I wanted to implement this logic:

- the EditorPage maintains model object and it's clone
- databindings persists changes into the model's clone object
- whenever binding
  changes I wanted to compare model object with it's clone to see if
  dirty state should be on/off

The problem is that when I use IChangeListener the changes are not yet persisted in the POJO - so I can not compare model with the clone. What is the correct approach to hook in to the state when the model is updated? Please note I would like to avoid replacing POJOs with Beans as POJOs are generated classes.